# How to solve the question related to continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**The question is** :

Let $f : \mathbb {R} \longrightarrow \mathbb {R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) = f(x^2)$.Then show that $f(x) = f(0)$ , $\forall x \in \mathbb {R}$.

How can I solve it?Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/338802/321264, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/980236/321264

Comment: I say duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Big hints:**

1. To begin with, $f(x)=f(\lvert x\rvert)$.
2. Let $0\le x<1$. $$f(x)-f(0)=f(x^2)-f(0)=f(x^4)-f(0)=f(x^8)-f(0)=\cdots$$
3. How much can $f(1)$ be, in light of (2) ?
4. Let $x>1$. $$f(x)-f(1)=f(x^{1/2})-f(1)=f(x^{1/4})-f(1)=\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** you can show that for all $x$ and all integers $n$, $f(x^{2^n})=f(x)$.

What happens letting $n \to \infty$ if $|x|<1$ ? What if $|x| \geq 1$ ?

Comment: You want $x^{2^n}$

Comment: @zhw.thanks edited

Comment: Yeah @Dark I have got it.Since $|x| < 1$ , $x^{2n}$ tends to $0$ as $n$ is tending to infinity.